# How to make a search using key/value pairs table?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have 2 domain classes

```
class Post {
    String name
}

class PostMeta { 
    String key 
    String value 
    Post post 
}
```

What I want to do, is a search using only one field "query", that returns all the Posts where "value" of PostMeta match with the query. The list of Posts must not contains duplicated elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def findPostsByValue(String criteria) {
   render PostMeta.createCriteria().list {
     projections {
        distinct("post")      
     }

     ilike "value", "%${criteria}%"
   }*.name
}
```